# How I call a function when I scrool for a specific section of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm just not sure how to call a function when I scroll to a specific section on my page.

**EXAMPLE:** 
I want to change the color of a text when I scroll to the article section. 
or... I want to hide a button when I scroll on the last sections of the page. 
or... I want to change the background of the page when I scroll to the footer.

I tried something like:

```js
function func() {
var paragraph = document.getElementById('p');
paragraph.style.color = 'red';
};
```

```html
<section>
<p id="p" onload="func()">
Test
</p>
</section>
```

Comment: See [`IntersectionObserver`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use intersection observer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver

```js
const observedElement = document.querySelector(".section-5");

const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio > 0) {
    console.log("visible");
    
    // if you want to execute once
    // remove the observer to avoid performance issues
    // intersectionObserver.unobserve(observedElement);
    // intersectionObserver.disconnect();
  }
});

intersectionObserver.observe(observedElement);
```

```css
.section {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section-1">
  section 1 (scroll down)
</div>
<div class="section section-2">
  section 2
</div>
<div class="section section-3">
  section 3
</div>
<div class="section section-4">
  section 4
</div>
<div class="section section-5">
  section 5 (log to console)
</div>
<div class="section section-6">
  section 6
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This function return true if the element is visible and false if not.**

```
function isInViewport(element) {
    // Get the bounding client rectangle position in the viewport
    var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // the code checks if it's *fully* visible
    if (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || 
        document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || 
        document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> You can add a scrolling event Listener and check if the targeted element is visible.

**this is a demo code you just have to change the variables to use it**

```
 targetElement = document.getElementById('element')
 targetElement.addEventListener('', () => {
      if (isInViewport(targetElement)) {
          // the code that you want to execute
          console.log("visible")
      }
 })
```